# Jakarta Mail with OpenJDK 11: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: jakarta.mail.Provider: Provider com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPProvider not a subtype

Tags: jakarta-mail, openjdk-11

I am migrating from java 8 to openjdk-11. Now the Mail (send email with smtp) do not more work. The project use openjdki 11 and jakarta.mail-2.0.0 on Win10. Later I added jakarta.activation-api-2.0.0.

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
    session.setDebug(debug);

    try {
        // create a message
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse(to));
        message.setSubject("Jakarta Mail API Test");
        message.setSentDate(new Date());

        MimeBodyPart mbp1 = new MimeBodyPart();
        mbp1.setText("This is a message body.\nHere's line two.");
        MimeBodyPart mbp2 = new MimeBodyPart();
        mbp2.setText("This is the text in the message attachment.", "us-ascii");
        Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();
        mp.addBodyPart(mbp1);
        message.setContent(mp);
        Transport.send(message);
    } catch (MessagingException mex) {
        mex.printStackTrace();
        Exception ex = null;
        if ((ex = mex.getNextException()) != null) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The code compiles, but they do not run:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: jakarta.mail.Provider: Provider com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPProvider not a subtype
at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:239)
at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:185)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:376)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
at jakarta.mail.Session.loadProviders(Session.java:964)
at jakarta.mail.Session.<init>(Session.java:254)
at jakarta.mail.Session.getInstance(Session.java:281)
at test.transport.main(transport.java:51)
C:\Users\<user>\Documents\NetbeansProjects12.0\AC99_Benutzer\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1370: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\<user>\Documents\NetbeansProjects12.0\AC99_Benutzer\nbproject\build-impl.xml:993: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: Are you [using Jakarta mail and Javamail in the same runtime](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mail/issues/527)?  Is the `jakarta.mail-api.jar` which only contains the stubs also the class/module path?  It shouldn't be used at runtime.

Comment: @jmehrens, what should I use instead please?

Answer (score 6):

Per [Jakarta Mail home page](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/mail/):  Artfact `jakarta.mail` is the implementation and `jakarta.mail-api` can only be used to compile against.  Only used with the `provided` dependency scope.

Use the link above and download the `jakarta.mail.jar`.  Remove the `jakarta.mail-api.jar`.  Add the `jakarta.mail.jar`

Comment: @Jaja Include your maven pom in the question.

Comment: I am not using maven pom but Netbeans libraries management