# Jakarta mail and javax mail in a single java application, Provider com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPProvider not a subtype

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I know there are already some questions around this, but answers to those doesn't not solve my issue hence creating one more question:

In my java application, I have included an 3rd party library which uses javax.mail:1.6.2 and provides email receive facility. Now, I also want to introduce email send facility (signed and encrypted email) for that I want to use SimpleJavaMail library which uses jakarta mail. So, in my application I added SimpleJavaMail dependency.

Now, the problem is if I try to send email using SimpleJavaMail then it's getting send but if I try to call retrieve email function from that 3rd party library it end up with this exception:

> java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.mail.Provider:
> com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPProvider not a subtype  at
> java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:589)    at
> java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:1237)
> at
> java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1265)
> at
> java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$2.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1300)
> at
> java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1385)
> at javax.mail.Session.getProviderByProtocol(Session.java:1017)  at
> javax.mail.Session.getProvider(Session.java:542)  at
> javax.mail.Session.getStore(Session.java:620)     at
> javax.mail.Session.getStore(Session.java:600)     at
> javax.mail.Session.getStore(Session.java:586)

So answer to this [Jakarta Mail with OpenJDK 11: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: jakarta.mail.Provider: Provider com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPProvider not a subtype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66224488/jakarta-mail-with-openjdk-11-java-util-serviceconfigurationerror-jakarta-mail) question says that jakarta.mail-api.jar should not be at runtime. I confirmed in my application as well it's not there. Still getting the error.

Is there any way to get rid of this?

Comment: Have you tried to update to JavaMail 1.6.7?  Do you have multiple JavaMail versions in different classloaders?  Turn on JavaMail debugging and check the output.

Comment: @jmehrens, I just tried by updating to 'com.sun.mail:jakarta.mail:1.6.7', still the same exception. Do you have multiple JavaMail versions --> basically I am creating a fat (shadow) jar of both the libraries and putting those into classpath of my application

Comment: Please attach the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) to the question.